# How do you access the accessibilityName of an NSColor?

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility, appkit, nscolor

I'm writing a multiplatform SwiftUI app, and I'd like to use `accessibilityName` to get human-readable names of colours. On iOS this works:

```swift
let myColor = Color.red
return UIColor(myColor).accessibilityName
```

and with arbitrary user-entered colours I get nice descriptions, such as 'dark blue', 'dark pink red' etc.

But for macOS, if I try:

```swift
return NSColor(myColor).accessibilityName
```

I get the error:

> Value of type 'NSColor' has no member 'accessibilityName'

I see in NSAccessibilityColor.h that NSColor should have this `accessibilityName` property from macOS 11 and up:

```objectivec
API_AVAILABLE(macos(11.0)) @protocol NSAccessibilityColor
@required
/*!
 @brief Returns a localized description of the color for use in accessibility attributes.
*/
@property(readonly) NSString *accessibilityName;
@end

@interface NSColor (NSAccessibilityColorConformance) <NSAccessibilityColor>
@end
```

I am targeting macOS 12.3. So how come I can't access this property? I also tried casting the NSColor to NSAccessibilityColor, but I get:

> Cannot find type 'NSAccessibilityColor' in scope

So it seems that whole header is ignored. Do I need to add a bridging header to get NSAccessibilityColor.h, even though I'm already importing AppKit?

The best alternative I've found (other than writing my own logic to create a name from the RGB values, which would be quite a sidetrack given the functionality already exists) is to use `NSColor.description`, but for arbitrary colours this just gives hex values, which is not particularly useful for accessibility.

Comment: That whole header is ignored (in macOS 11 SDK), see `NSAccessibility.h`.

Comment: @Willeke Oh wow, so it is! `// #import <AppKit/NSAccessibilityColor.h> - this caused a build failure (60459719), and needs to be disabled until 60467092 is addressed`

I'm just going to go with `NSColor(color).value(forKey: "accessibilityName") as? String` then; it works, and it's not technically private API if it's commented out due to a bug! Thanks!